# Access Convolutional Neural Network Parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I try to switch from pytorch to tensorflow and since the model now seems to be a fixed thing in tensorflow, i stumble upon a problem when working with Convolutional Neural Networks.

I have a very simple model, just one Conv1D layer and a kernel with size 2.
I want to train it on a small Configuration, say 16 input size and then export the training results on a 32 input size.

How can i access the 3 parameters in this network? (2 kernel, 1 bias) I want to do so to apply them for the higher size case. I struggle because i need to pre-define a input size of the model, this was not the case with pytorch.

Thanks for answering, I've only found outdated answers to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.layers[0].get_weights()` yields the weights of the first layer, assuming `model` is a `tf.keras.Model` object.